# React-Native - How to create a disabled style for the TouchableOpacity component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I apply disabled style for a TouchableOpacity component?

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={styles.buttonWrapper } 
  onPress={this.userLogin.bind(this)}
  disabled={ !this.state.username || !this.state.password }
>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the same condition as your disabled prop.

Something like this should work :

```
style={!this.state.username || !this.state.password ? styles.disabled : styles.buttonWrapper}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to have a disabled style for an element in `React-Native` or `React` is something like this:

```
  style={
    (!this.state.username || !this.state.password)
    ? {...styles.buttonWrapper, ...styles.buttonDisabled}
    : styles.buttonWrapper
  }
```

**See in action: 
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-snyder-frr1n)**

With using this example, you don't need to have duplicate styles for the button you just need to define disabled style like `backgroundColor` or `color` for the disabled button in `styles.buttonDisabled`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use opacity for show disable
`

```
const [disabledStyle, setDisabledStyle] = useState<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled) {
      setDisabledStyle({opacity: 0.5});
    } else {
      setDisabledStyle({opacity: 1});
    }
  }, [disabled]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      disabled={disabled}
      style={[disabledStyle]}
      onPress={() => callBack()}>
      <View>
        <View>{children}</View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using styled components this would work.

```
export const CustomButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    opacity: ${({ disabled }) => (disabled ? 0.5 : 1)};
`;
```